# C++Builder Make a copy of the TDBGrid Columns = overload resolution selected deleted operation '='

Tags: c++builder

I want to make a copy of the columns in a TDBGrid and tried to use:

```
DynamicArray<TColumn> columnslist;
columnslist.Length=DBGrid1->Columns->Count;

for (UINT i=0;i<DBGrid1->Columns->Count;i++) {
    columnslist[i]=*DBGrid1->Columns->Items[i]; // <- error
}
```

But that gives:

```
overload resolution selected deleted operator '=' 
systobj.h(45): candidate function has been explicitly deleted
```

Is there no copy constructor?  What is the method to make a copy of a `TColumn`

TIA!!

Comment: What are you going to use the `TColumn` copies for? If you want references to `TColumns`, just make it `DynamicArray<TColumn*> columnslist;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo After loading from stream I need to check if there is a new column that the stream hadn't saved otherwise the new column(s) would be missing.  If I use the pointer, after the load, those pointers are invalid.  So I want to save the columns before trying to load, then I'll check for missing columns and add them.

Comment: I see. And it's not the values you want to restore? You've serialized the actual `TColumn`s?

Comment: yes it's using the DBGrid->Columns->LoadFromStream()  (save prior) so I want to just save the columns before loading, then check after and just copy over the column.  I guess I'll have to copy the key pieces but things like Fonts and such I see pascal code uses "Assign()" I have to look that up... Then you have the `Data::Db::TField* Field` etc..

Comment: Ok, I see.  Then I don't know :)

Comment: I'll just build my own structure with some basic details and not all the other stuff..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, feel free to add Exception Handling, Menus, PickLists, etc.. for others that may want to use it.

```
struct sColumnDetails {
    TAlignment Alignment;
    TColumnButtonStyle ButtonStyle;
    TColor Color;
    UINT DropDownRows;
    bool Expanded;
    String FieldName;
    TImeMode ImeMode;
    TImeName ImeName;
    String TitleCaption;
    TAlignment TitleAlignment;
    int Width;
    bool Visible;

    void Assign(TColumn *col)
    {
        Alignment=col->Alignment;
        ButtonStyle=col->ButtonStyle;
        Color=col->Color;
        DropDownRows=col->DropDownRows;
        Expanded=col->Expanded;
        FieldName=col->FieldName;
        ImeMode=col->ImeMode;
        ImeName=col->ImeName;
        TitleCaption=col->Title->Caption;
        TitleAlignment=col->Title->Alignment;
        Width=col->Width;
        Visible=col->Visible;
    }

    void AssignTo(TColumn *col)
    {
        col->Alignment=Alignment;
        col->ButtonStyle=ButtonStyle;
        col->Color=Color;
        col->DropDownRows=DropDownRows;
        col->Expanded=Expanded;
        col->FieldName=FieldName;
        col->ImeMode=ImeMode;
        col->ImeName=ImeName;
        col->Title->Caption=TitleCaption;
        col->Title->Alignment=TitleAlignment;
        col->Width=Width;
        col->Visible=Visible;
    }
};
```

Before Loading:

```
UINT numcols=reinterpret_cast<TDBGrid*>(control)->Columns->Count;
// save columns that should exist (that may not after load if new)
DynamicArray<sColumnDetails> columnslist;
columnslist.Length=numcols;

for (UINT i=0;i<numcols;i++) {
    columnslist[i].Assign(reinterpret_cast<TDBGrid*>(control)->Columns->Items[i]);
}
```

After Loading:

```
// add missing columns
for (UINT i=0;i<columnslist.Length;i++) {
    bool found=false;
    for (UINT j=0;j<reinterpret_cast<TDBGrid*>(control)->Columns->Count;j++) {
        // check for match
        const TColumn *dbgridcol=reinterpret_cast<TDBGrid*>(control)->Columns->Items[j];
        if (columnslist[i].FieldName==dbgridcol->FieldName && columnslist[i].TitleCaption==dbgridcol->Title->Caption) {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        // add missing column
        TColumn *nc=reinterpret_cast<TDBGrid*>(control)->Columns->Add();
        if (nc) {
            columnslist[i].AssignTo(nc);
        }
    }
}
```